# How can I create a dictionary of dictionaries of Unique Key Pairs?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with columns `IssuerId` and `Sedol`. The `IssuerId`s will be the same in some instances but the `Sedol` will always be different.

I would like to create a dictionary or multi-level index that aggregates these such that I can easily traverse them. For instance I currently have:

```
IssuerID Sedol
1          1
1          2
2          3
3          4
```

And I want to somehow create:

```
[{1: [1,2]},{2: 3},{3:4}]
```

Comment: Your desired output is not a valid python object. Did you mean `[{1: [1,2]},{2: 3},{3:4}]`?

Comment: Yes I meant a list of dictionaries, apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `groupBy` + `apply(list)` and then call `to_dict`, you get:

```
d = df.groupby("IssuerID")["Sedol"].apply(list).to_dict()
print(d)
#{1: [1, 2], 2: [3], 3: [4]}
```

Now just reformat `d` to get your desired output.

If you want a dictionary, use a dict comprehension:

```
new_dict = {k: v if len(v) > 1 else v[0] for k, v in d.items()}
print(new_dict)
#{1: [1, 2], 2: 3, 3: 4}
```

If you want a list of dictionaries, use a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [{k: v if len(v) > 1 else v[0]} for k, v in d.items()]
print(new_list )
#[{1: [1, 2]}, {2: 3}, {3: 4}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `groupby`

```
l=[{x:y.tolist()}for x , y in df.groupby('IssuerID')['Sedol']]
l
[{1: [1, 2]}, {2: [3]}, {3: [4]}]
```